# How to escape the character \ in PHP and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, escaping

I have this line of code and the \ is generating problems (at least in the highlighting of Sublime Text. How Can I escape this character?

```
text = text.replace(":\","<img src='images/Smilleys_08.png' class='smilley' />");
text = text.replace(":-\","<img src='images/Smilleys_08.png' class='smilley' />");
```

Also the same code needs to be in PHP and it goes like this

```
$tempText = str_replace(":\","<img src='images/Smilleys_08.png' class='smilley' />",$tempText);
$tempText = str_replace(":-\","<img src='images/Smilleys_08.png' class='smilley' />",$tempText);
```

Comment: "\" is generally escaped as "\\"

Comment: With another backslash: \\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you would escape any other character: Add a `\` in front of it:

```
text = text.replace(":\\","<img src='images/Smilleys_08.png' class='smilley' />");
```

This counts for both php as JavaScript.

Working example:

```js
alert(":\\ bla bla :\\ test".replace(":\\","<img src='images/Smilleys_08.png' class='smilley' />"));
```

Just keep in mind that a string replace only replaces the first occurrence of the search string, as shown in the demo.

To fix that, try this regex replace:

```js
alert(":\\ bla bla :\\ test".replace(/:\\/g,"<img src='images/Smilleys_08.png' class='smilley' />"));
```

Comment: I did that and it works. Only problem is that after the image has been placed the remaining \ is still visible.

Comment: what is the content of your text variable before the replace?

Comment: Comment text. Example: Text text text text :\ :) Text ;)

Comment: The update you did with the RE works but still I got <image>\ <image>\ <image>\ as a result. This backslash still remains.

Comment: What's in your string o.O You _could_ try this regex instead: `(/:\\+/g`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks! Final question. Because I see the replace method only does it once as you said what is the regex pattern to follow. For example :)?   

  /:)/g does not seem to work.

By the way the PHP replace method replaces all occurances in the string.

Comment: `/:\\+/g` That is the complete regex. `:\\+` is the smiley part. `/smileyHere/g`

Comment: Won't work with :). For example '/:)+/g' is not working.

Comment: Remove the quotes and `+` there: `/:)/g`

Comment: Ok. Found it. Needed to escape the parenthesis.
text = text.replace(/:\)/g,"<img src='images/Smilleys_01.png' class='smilley' />");